# List of abbreviations/acronyms packages for non-English languages

Tags: languages, acronyms, cyrillic

Is there any `LaTeX` package for acronyms/abbreviations that specifically targets Cyrillic (Russian/Ukrainian) users, with all that different cases (Dative, Accusative, etc.) they have in their languages.

I know about general packages for creating acronyms/abbreviations lists: `glossaries`, `acronym`, `nomenclature`, but they mostly deal with plural forms and not with cases.

EDIT: An answer

I looked again closely at the `glossaries` package. I have found out that it supports up to 6 user defined forms of acronyms/abbreviations, so you can use them to specify different cases you need.

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at what the German-speaking community did. I am not sure there is what you seek, but they have quite a few cases too, and since there is a wide user base, there are a lot of packages (though most of them are in German).

Comment: @ienissei, thank you, I'll try to pursue that direction.

Comment: There is no specific package for the language German. It isn't possible. The Dative or Accusative doesn't follow any specific  rules. The same in Russian. What you can to -- define your own commands whereby the Definitions of the different cases must be set by you. Whatever I think if you create a minimal example you will increase your chance getting an answer.

Comment: @GKalnytskyi: Not yet ;-)

Comment: Sorry, @MarcoDaniel, I have hit `Enter` at wrong time and had to delete my previous comment. I'll repeat it here. I came to the exactly the idea of specifying all the cases of the abbreviation at the beginning of the document and than indicating what case you want to use in text with the command, but I thought that it might have been done by someone. But that might be an overkill, because for now I am satisfied with `nomenclature` package. I just define new abbreviation to the list as I write. Thanks for your comment. :)